# Databinding to the width of a form

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, layouttransform

I am trying to dynamically scale my UI of my WPF based application, I'd like to use the ratio of the current resolution and my native resolution using something like this:

```
    <Grid.LayoutTransform>
        <ScaleTransform CenterX="0" CenterY="0" ScaleX="{Binding FormWidth/NativeREsolution}" ScaleY="{Binding FormWidth/NativeREsolution}"/>
    </Grid.LayoutTransform>
```

The reason why I found scale transform is it scales all the UI elements within the container, including frames and subpages.

is there anyway to do this?

Alternatively is there a better way to dynamically scale an application depending on the size of the window?

Comment: what? is this WPF? you don't really need that. There is no enough info in this question to provide an answer. Please clarify

Comment: Yes it is WPF, added the tag and hopefully added enough.  What I need is to dynamically scale my application as I resize it.

Comment: I don't understand. WPF is resolution-independent by nature. Why would you apply a `ScaleTransform`?

Comment: In WPF they are Windows or Pages - not forms.   I think you are making the too complex.

Comment: @Blam I hate it when they call a `Window` a "form".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[WPF is Resolution Independent by nature.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7275257/643085)

```
<Window ..>
   <Grid>

   <!-- Content here -->

   </Grid>
</Window>
```

The above XAML will cause the `Grid` to stretch to the Window size. No horrendous winforms-like hacks required.

**Edit:**

if you want `Everything` (including Font Sizes) to scale within a `Window`, just use a Viewbox:

```
<Window>
   <Viewbox>
       <Grid>

       <!-- Content here -->

       </Grid>
   </Viewbox>
</Window>
```

Comment: What about all of the elements within?  Will they scale?  Will fonts scale?  The main reason I found ScaleTransform to work well is because I have several frames with different pages within them.

Comment: yup that fixed it.  wow.  I cant believe I overlooked putting the entire grid in a viewbox.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution would be to use a Viewbox but it's also possible to calculate the scale on Window resize quite simply.

**ViewBox**

```
<Window x:Class="MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Viewbox Stretch="Uniform">
    <Grid>
        <Label>
            Hello world
        </Label>
    </Grid>
</Viewbox>
</Window>
```

**Manual scaling**

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" 
    Name="myMainWindow"
    Width="200" Height="250">
<Grid Name="MainGrid" SizeChanged="MainGrid_SizeChanged">
    <Grid.LayoutTransform>
        <ScaleTransform x:Name="ApplicationScaleTransform"
                        CenterX="0"
                        CenterY="0"
                        ScaleX="{Binding ElementName=myMainWindow, Path=ScaleValue}"
                        ScaleY="{Binding ElementName=myMainWindow, Path=ScaleValue}" />
    </Grid.LayoutTransform>
    <Grid VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="150">
        <TextBlock FontSize="20" Text="Hello World" Margin="5" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
        <Button Content="Button" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

where the grid is scaled using a LayoutTransform that determines the ScaleX & ScaleY properties by referring to a coded ScaleValue dependency property that is calculated during the Window_Resize event using code looking something like

```
#region ScaleValue Dependency Property

    public static readonly DependencyProperty ScaleValueProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("ScaleValue", typeof(double), typeof(MainWindow), new UIPropertyMetadata(1.0, new PropertyChangedCallback(OnScaleValueChanged), new CoerceValueCallback(OnCoerceScaleValue)));

    private static object OnCoerceScaleValue(DependencyObject o, object value)
    {
        MainWindow mainWindow = o as MainWindow;
        if (mainWindow != null)
            return mainWindow.OnCoerceScaleValue((double)value);
        else
            return value;
    }

    private static void OnScaleValueChanged(DependencyObject o, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        MainWindow mainWindow = o as MainWindow;
        if (mainWindow != null)
            mainWindow.OnScaleValueChanged((double)e.OldValue, (double)e.NewValue);
    }

    protected virtual double OnCoerceScaleValue(double value)
    {
        if (double.IsNaN(value))
            return 1.0f;

        value = Math.Max(0.1, value);
        return value;
    }

    public double ScaleValue
    {            
        get
        {
            return (double)GetValue(ScaleValueProperty);
        }
        set
        {
            SetValue(ScaleValueProperty, value);
        }
    }
    #endregion


    private void CalculateScale()
        {
            double yScale = ActualHeight / 250f;
            double xScale = ActualWidth / 200f;
            double value = Math.Min(xScale, yScale);
            ScaleValue = (double)OnCoerceScaleValue(MainGrid, value);
        }
```

Comment: If I recall correctly, the issue with the viewbox was that a single viewbox could only hold a single element.  Though that might work now because we are using frames to hold our pages.

Comment: @Herrozerro if you're "displaying multiple pages" (whatever that means) just put a `ContentPresenter` inside the Viewbox and Bind the `Content` property. I don't see what the big deal is that you want to do it in procedural code.